# ¿How I load Richtexbox.rtf from dataBase with Datatype XML?

Tags: xml, richtextbox, dbcontext, rtf

In my database I have a column of XML datatype. I use an RTF to XML converter and I using DbContext.

How do I load Richtexbox.rtf from the database with datatype `XML`?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table] 
(
    [Id] INT IDENTITY (777000000, 1) NOT NULL,
    [XmlData] XML NULL
)
```

My code:

```
var ht = (from h in db.Table where (h.ID == 777000001) select h);

if (ht.Count() > 0)
{
    var xml = ht.FirstOrDefault().XmlData;

    // Code to convert....
    richTexBox.rtf = ????;
}
```

Comment: RTF isn't XML - I don't think using `XML` as your column's datatype makes sense here....

Comment: Ok, I need to save RTF in database with images and tables content. What should be the best way to save this information if a TEXT data type has size restriction?.